# No pool was specified, although a pool is specified in the Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a problem in the ADOS system that the pipeline fails because there is no "pool" specified. Also the validation shows this error. However, I have defined a pool.

```yaml
trigger: 
  branches:
    include:
      - 'main'

pool: 
  name: my-pool
  demands:
    - my_pool_demands

[...]
```

Do you have any clue?

I tried to

- run the pipeline with other pool
- run the pipeline without pool
- run the pipeline with minimum tasks (only build task)
- run the pipeline without any comments in it

Nothing could change the "No pool was specified" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of modifying my pipeline and reading the documentation, I finally figured out how to fix this problem. It is not because of the yaml file. The error must be related to the pipeline. **The solution is to create a new pipeline. The same yaml file will work fine in the new pipeline.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the yaml file to create a new pipeline, but then you have to edit the pipeline, click the top right dots button, triggers, then YAML, then pipeline, and select the pool under "Default agent pool for YAML"

Consider going to this issue on the feedback hub and commenting on the "solution" to let Microsoft know we'd like this fixed. We shouldn't have to do a workaround.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Auto-created-pipeline-from-yaml-return-e/10054547?q=yaml+no+pool+was+specified

Answer (score 1):

Edit the pipeline and check if there's any weird red warnings. That's what I did and somehow the agent pool setting was cleared out.